# How to send data from background service to main application in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am running a background servie and at a specific time, I want to send some data in form of JSON string to my application. It may happen that my app is currently terminated, so I am using app laucher plugin to open my application. After opening the application, I want to send some data to application so as to display it. So, how can I send the message and recieve it in my main application (I will have to change the state of my widget once I recieve the data)?

Comment: Do you use a package for running the background service if yes which do you use?

Comment: I am using WorkManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure if this works, but I think instead of somehow sending the data from the background service to the main application you could probably save it in shared preferences or local database or using hive or something similar and simply retrieve it in your main application.

Comment: O yeah, never though of that! Darn it! That was so simple! Well thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Definitely agree with above answer , But if you want to secure your application more then you can use [Flutter_Secure_Storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage). It is alternative to [Shared_Preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) :)

Comment: Thanks for that! I would look into it! (I wish I could accept more than one answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a port for each isolate (the main and the background) and listen to the events, Eg:. you can send your data:

```dart
IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('mainIsolate')?.send('Hi from background');
```

and listen to the event:

```dart
void initListinPort() {
  ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();
  IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(port.sendPort, 'mainIsolate');
  // Listen for messages from the background isolate
  port.listen((msg) {
    print('message from background service: $msg');
  });
}
```

and i think it's much better than store and restore your message, since you dont have to use `await` or any overhead logic and you'll be able to send all types of data `Null` `bool` `int` `double` `String` `List` `Map` `Set` `TransferableTypedData` `SendPort` `Capability` `Type`

however, sometimes you may have to stringify your object